# Multiplying by negative 1 in TypeScript + React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some state variable

```
const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = useState<1 | -1>(1);
```

I have a button which can modify the state variable like so

```
setSortDirection(sortDirection * -1);
```

However I get the warning

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<1 | -1>'
```

How should I go about implementing this functionality? The `sortDirection` can only ever be -1 or 1, and multiplying by -1 should also adhere to that rule.

Of course I'm also open to other implementations, I don't need to have `sortDirection: 1 | -1.`

Comment: So you have declared state to be either 1 or -1 number literals. TS won't do math and calculate the result of sortDirection*-1 as some literal. If you're making it toggleable, just `sortDirection === -1 ? 1: -1`. You can also set up a function that has return types of -1 or 1. `toggleSort(direction) { if (direction > 0) { return -1 } return 1}` that will have have the right number literal types.

Comment: I think you are looking for boolean instead of <-1 | 1>

Comment: The result type of any mathematical operation in typescript is `number`, even if the exact value of the operands is known. In addition to the ternary suggestion, you can also just cast the value: `setSortDirection(-1 * sortDirection as 1 | -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript can't infer that `sortDirection * -1` will always be `1 | -1`

But you can do following :

```
setSortDirection(sortDirection > 0 ? -1 : 1);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAZg9jBcEC0BGCAfCaC8WDcAUAbDBLiRAFTJoD0tEA0gPLFxnTsB8EADBAH4aERHQbNmjCEA)

Anyway, you will be better off using a `boolean` instead of this 2-state number.